# Dynamic menu and css

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

hope you can help me

I tryning to make at dynamic menu system

but i cant get the submenu action to work right :( 
you always have to select an item of the submenu twice before the submenu stays open :(

```
<?php 
include '../inc/db_connect.php';

// Select all entries from the menu table
// $result=mysql_query("SELECT id, label, link, parent FROM menu ORDER BY parent, sort, label");
// Create a multidimensional array to conatin a list of items and parents

$sql = <<<SQL
   SELECT id, label, link, parent, class
   FROM menu
   ORDER BY parent, sort, label
 SQL;

if(!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)){
  die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}



$menu = array(
  'items' => array(),
  'parents' => array()
);

// Builds the array lists with data from the menu table
while ($items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
// Creates entry into items array with current menu item id ie. $menu['items'][1]
$menu['items'][$items['id']] = $items;
// Creates entry into parents array. Parents array contains a list of all items with children
$menu['parents'][$items['parent']][] = $items['id'];
}

// Menu builder function, parentId 0 is the root
function buildMenu($parent, $menu)
{
$menu = call_user_func(modifymenu, $parent,$menu);

 $html = "";
if (isset($menu['parents'][$parent]))
 {
  $html .= "
  <ul>\n";

  foreach ($menu['parents'][$parent] as $itemId)
   {

      if(!isset($menu['parents'][$itemId]))
      {
         $html .= "<li class ='".$menu['items'][$itemId]['class']."'>\n  <a href='?p=".$menu['items'][$itemId]['link']."'>".$menu['items'][$itemId]['label']."</a>\n</li> \n";
      }
      if(isset($menu['parents'][$itemId]))
      {
        if ($_SESSION['submenu'] == $menu['items'][$itemId]['id'] ) {
              $menu['items'][$itemId]['class'] = "active open";
          }
         $html .= "
         <li class ='submenu ".$menu['items'][$itemId]['class']." '>\n  <a href='?p=".$menu['items'][$itemId]['link']."'>".$menu['items'][$itemId]['label']."</a> \n";
         $html .= buildMenu($itemId, $menu);
         $html .= "</li> \n";
      }
   }
   $html .= "</ul> \n";
}
return $html;
}
echo buildMenu(0, $menu);

function modifymenu ($parent, $menu) {

$ref = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : null;

foreach ($menu['parents'][$parent] as $itemId)
   {

         if($ref == $menu['items'][$itemId]['link'] ) {
           $menu['items'][$itemId]['class'] = "active";

           if (isset($menu['items'][$itemId]['parent'])) {
             $_SESSION['submenu'] = $menu['items'][$itemId]['parent'];
           }else{
            $_SESSION['submenu'] = '';
           }

          }
  }

   return $menu;

   }

   function modifyparent ($parent, $menu) {

$ref = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : null;

foreach ($menu['parents'][$parent] as $itemId)
   {

         if($ref == $menu['items'][$itemId]['link'] ) {
           $menu['items'][$itemId]['class'] = "active";
           $_SESSION['submenu'] = $menu['items'][$itemId]['parent'];
          }
  }

  return $menu;

  }
```

Hope somebody can stop the error

PS. Im a noop at php and i know it but there is only one way to get better :)

Comment: You can see it live at http://plaq.dk/classes/sidebar.class.php

Comment: That's a mess of code. Look into recursive functions. As far as 'you have to select an item of the submenu twice', once your actual menu is established, the rest is up to CSS to actually hide/show the sub-menus.

Comment: The problem is not CSS but my function "modifymenu" the part where it sets "submenu" via Session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with something like this:

```
//Call all menu items from database into array
$dbArray = #whatever database code you choose
```

You can separate top level links by using a `parent` field in your database.

Then have it process through recursive functions:

```
function createMenu($dbArray){
  foreach($dbArray as $key => $value){
    if($parent=='top')
     //establish as top link
      createLink($key);
    if($parent=='$id')
     //if parent matches id then add as sub-menu of this top level item
      createLink($key);
  }      
}

function createLink($linkData){
  foreach($linkData as $keys => $values){
    //add <a> and other per-link items
  }
}
```

I realize this is a rough answer but hopefully it guides you to a more simple solution!